# Updating association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship (Scenario and Step). I needed to save the order of the steps within a scenario so i added a third entity called ScenarioToStep with a displayOrder property.

```
class ScenarioToStep
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hakisa\Bundle\GettingStartedBundle\Entity\Scenario", inversedBy="scenarioToStep")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="scenario_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Hakisa\Bundle\GettingStartedBundle\Entity\Scenario
 */
private $scenario;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hakisa\Bundle\GettingStartedBundle\Entity\Step", inversedBy="stepToScenario")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="step_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 * @var Hakisa\Bundle\GettingStartedBundle\Entity\Step
 */
private $step;

/**
 * Order of the step in the scenario
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 *
 * @var integer
 */
private $displayOrder;
```

The 3 properties makes the primary key so i can have a step multiple times in a scenario

I have a UI where i can add steps via drag n drop, remove steps or sort step. This UI send an array to PHP where the index is the position and the value is the id of the step.

```
array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 1,
    4 => 4
)
```

I want to update my Scenario entity to match this new ordering. I first tried something like:

```
$scenario->getScenarioToStep()->clear();
foreach ($tabIds as $pos => $stepId) {
    $sts = new ScenarioToStep();
    $sts->setScenario($scenario)->setStep($step)->setOrder($pos);
    $scenario->getScenarioToStep()->add($sts);
}
```

but i end up with duplicate key errors

if i do similar thing but instead of instanciating a new scenario i ask entity manager for a reference (proxy) then the association table is always empty

Thanks to anyone who has an idea on how i should perform my save